# How to debug document not available for search in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to search and fetch the documents from Elasticsearch but in some cases, I am not getting the updated documents. By updated I mean, we update the documents periodically in Elasticsearch. The documents in ElasticSearch are updated at an interval of 30 seconds, and the number of documents could range from 10-100 Thousand. I am aware that the update is generally a slow process in Elasticsearch.

I am suspecting it is happening because Elasticsearch though accepted the documents but the documents were not available for searching. Hence I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way to measure the time between indexing and the documents being available for search? There is setting in Elasticsearch which can log more information in Elasticsearch logs?
2. Is there a setting in Elasticsearch which enables logging whenever the merge operation happens?
3. Any other suggestion to help in optimizing the performance?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you set refresh_interval to 30 seconds?

Comment: No, I am using the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `refresh_interval` parameter is set to 1 second, so unless you changed this parameter each update will be searchable after maximum 1 second.

If you want to make the results searchable as soon as you have performed the update operation you can use the [refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html) parameter.

Using `refresh=wait_for` the endpoint will respond once a refresh has occured. If you use `refresh=true` a refresh operation will be triggered. Be careful using `refresh=true` if you have many update since it can impact performances.

Comment: I am using the default setting and doing a search query at an interval of 30 seconds. I'll experiment with calling refresh before searching. Thanks!